Python script opens empty cmd windows
I have this code for start and stopping xampp apache and mysql.
import subprocess
import os
import time
import argparse
import sys

# XAMPP installation path
xampp_path = 'D:\\projects'  # Get path from environment variable or use default

# Seconds to wait for services to start/stop
wait_time = 2

# Function to start a service using batch files
def start_service(batch_file):
    command = os.path.join(xampp_path, batch_file)
    if os.path.isfile(command):
        print(f"Starting service with {batch_file}...")
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
        time.sleep(wait_time)  # Give it some time to start
        print(f"Service started successfully with {batch_file}.")
    else:
        print(f"Batch file {batch_file} does not exist.")

# Function to stop a service using batch files
def stop_service(batch_file):
    command = os.path.join(xampp_path, batch_file)
    if os.path.isfile(command):
        print(f"Stopping service with {batch_file}...")
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
        time.sleep(wait_time)  # Give it some time to stop
        print(f"Attempted to stop service with {batch_file}.")
    else:
        print(f"Batch file {batch_file} does not exist.")

# Function to forcefully kill a service by its process name
def kill_service(service_name):
    try:
        subprocess.run(f"taskkill /F /IM {service_name}", check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
        print(f"Service {service_name} killed successfully.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error killing {service_name}: {e.stderr.decode()}")

# Parse command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Start or stop XAMPP services.")
parser.add_argument("--start", action="store_true", help="Start XAMPP services")
parser.add_argument("--stop", action="store_true", help="Stop XAMPP services")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Start or stop XAMPP services based on command line arguments
if args.start:
    # Start Apache and MySQL
    start_service("apache_start.bat")
    time.sleep(wait_time)  # Wait a few seconds before starting MySQL to ensure Apache starts properly
    start_service("mysql_start.bat")

elif args.stop:
    # Stop Apache and MySQL
    stop_service("apache_stop.bat")
    stop_service("mysql_stop.bat")

    # Kill lingering processes after attempting to stop them gracefully
    kill_service("xampp-control.exe")  # xampp
    kill_service("httpd.exe")  # Apache
    kill_service("mysqld.exe")  # MySQL

    # Check if services are still running
    def check_service_stopped(service_name):
        tasklist_output = subprocess.check_output("tasklist", shell=True).decode()
        if service_name in tasklist_output:
            print(f"{service_name} is still running.")
        else:
            print(f"{service_name} has been stopped.")

    # Check Apache and MySQL status
    check_service_stopped("httpd.exe")  # Apache
    check_service_stopped("mysqld.exe")  # MySQL

    print("Apache and MySQL services have been stopped.")

else:
    print("Please specify --start or --stop parameter.")

sys.exit(0)


I have the file in a folder that is set in environment variables, so i'm able to run it from anywhere using:
xampp.py --start

or to stop
xampp.py --stop

Problem:
both works. but when i run xampp.py --stop it opens py.exe does its job and closes it. but along with that it opens 2 new cmd windows. and i cannot figure out why and from where it opens those.
both cmd window shows this:
The system cannot find the path specified.

D:\projects>


What happens if you try directly running the batch scripts at the command line? And why are there separate start_service and stop_service if they do the same thing? If it depends on what the batch script contains, then the Python function names are not actually giving you information, and in fact are just as likely to deceive you.

normally i run it vscode cmd line. if i try the cmd.exe outside vscode inside the folder, it does the same thing. does the job in 1 cmd window and opened 2 new cmd window. also start_service andstop_service maybe there for the printing diff. message. its just bad type of code for tasks to save time.

Sorry guys, I think actually it was the issue from XAMPP's bat file itself mysql_stop.bat and apache_stop.bat. code inside them was not finding a file.
the issue rightly pointed out in this Apachefriends Forum
as suggested, I have modified the function to this
def stop_service(service_name):
    command = ["killprocess.bat", service_name]
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    if process.returncode != 0:
        print(f"Failed to stop {service_name}. Error: {error.decode()}")
    else:
        print(f"Successfully stopped {service_name}. Output: {output.decode()}")


Not enough reputation to comment but try commenting out your two calls to check_service_stopped() to see if the windows stop opening. subprocess.Popen(shell=True) can cause unexpected behavior so it would be good to check on your shell configuration

yes, I actually checked without those, it still opens the empty cmd windows. i believe its somewhere in the stop_service func, as the --stop flag is using that
